# Latest compatible versions among Neo4j, Python, and py2neo?

Tags: python, python-3.x, neo4j, version, py2neo

Using fairly recent "pip install"s, I'm building a web app using Python (v. 3.8.1, considering upgrading to 3.8.2), Neo4j (v. 4.0.2. considering 4.0.3), and py2neo (v. 4.3.0), and I'm running into various issues (import problems, no such function, etc).

After banging my head over these for a while, I see (for example) that the py2neo v.4 Handbook says it supports Python up through v. 3.7.x, and Neo4j up through 3.5.x...but I don't know if those docs are up to date and/or compatible with the later versions of the other products, or if instead I'm doing something wrong in my code.

Py2neo in particular seems to have been doing some major gymnastics lately (e.g., find_one(), --> deprecated, use NodeSelector(), --> deprecated, use NodeSelection(), --> deprecated, use MatchSelection(), etc.).

Can someone tell me what are the latest versions of each of these that will play well together? If I opt for each of those versions, then maybe I can concentrate on my actual code. Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [The Py2neo v4 Handbook](https://py2neo.org/v4/):

> The following versions of Python and Neo4j are supported:
>
> - Python 2.7 / 3.4 / 3.5 / 3.6 / 3.7
> - Neo4j 3.2 / 3.3 / 3.4 / 3.5 (the latest point release of each version is recommended)

As a personal experience, `Python 3.6.9` + `neo4j 3.5.7` + `py2neo 4.3.0` work fine.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try dropping back to those versions. I know that Python's up into the 3.8's, Neo4j's up into the 4's, and Py2neo's up into the 5's...but I'll go for anything that works! Much appreciated.